# Bash command chain not terminating when expected

Tags: bash, shell

**While working on a project toolchain,** it became apparent that I do not understand `bash` lists.

From the manual:
<sub>"manual": `man bash`</sub>

> **Lists:**
>
> A  list  is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>   operators ;, &, &&, or ||,
>
> [...]
>
> Of these list operators, && and || have equal precedence, followed by ;
>   and &, which have equal precedence.
>
> [...]
>
> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more  pipelines  separated  by
>   the  &&  and  || control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are
>   executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> *command1 && command2*
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an  exit  status
>   of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> *command1 || command2*
>
> command2  is  executed  if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit
>   status. The return status of AND and OR lists is the  exit  status  of
>   the last command executed in the list.
>   <sub>[Formatting mine]</sub>

Rather than code that looks like this:

```
command1

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    command2
fi;
```

We can just do this:

```
command1 && command2
```

---

**In one of the scripts I have,** I have code that is functionally equivalent to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

s () { return 0; }
f () { return 1; }
l () { echo "Y"; }

#Why does this output "Y"?
f && f || true && s && l

#This does what I want:
f && { f; s && l; }
```

---

**In the above example,** I would expect (and desperately want) `f || true && s && l` to run only if `f` doesn't fail. But alas, I must use `f && { f; s && l; }` to get the functionality I want.

What am I misunderstanding? Why does the chain "keep going" past the first `&&`?

*Shouldn't the command chain stop running after `f &&` because "command2  is  executed  if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status"?*

---

**PS:** I would expect it to function like this.

```
if (f == 0) {
    if (f != 0) {
        if (0 == 0) {
            if (s == 0) {
                l;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Equal precedence, left associative: `f && f || true && s && l` parses as `(((f && f) || true) && s) && l` (not actually valid shell syntax, parens used for demonstration only). `... || true` is always true, so `s` always runs.

Comment: @melpomene: Ouch! It appears like I don't understand equal precedence. (I normally use parentheses in `if` statements.)

Comment: Other than a chain of `&&` or a chain of `||`, it's best to use an explicit `if` statement. Mixing the two is never going to be clearer, and will frequently be more bug-prone.

Comment: @chepner: Thank you. That makes sense. What thinkest thou of using {} to *force* a specific order as I have in the code I'm currently using?

Comment: It's correct, but I don't think it's as readable as `if f; then f; s && l; fi` (which in a script would not be put on one line, but properly split and indented).

Comment: @chepner: Since I have 3 lines that are similar but not identical, it just keeps it a little cleaner in my opinion to use {} where appropriate. (I didn't know that you could do `if f; ...`, so thanks for pointing that out. Aforetime, I would have done `f; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; ...`.)

Answer (score 1):

> **Why does this output "Y"?**

```
f && f || true && s && l
is the same as
( 
  (
    ( 
      (
        f && f
      ) || true 
    ) && s 
  ) && l
)
```

but s=false

```
( 
  (
    f && f
  ) || true 
) && s
-> false
```

In fact

```
f && f || true && s && l -> l
```

> **About the PS**

```
not (f=0) || not (f!=0) || not (0=0) || not (s=0) ||  l
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but could you add a little explanation? I'm not sure *why* `f && b && c` is equivalent to `((f && b) && c)`...

Comment: @JefréN because it's left associative, you read from left to right. I'ts depends on the language, but it's the most frequent. Good luck about your  project.

Comment: Why doesn't it *quit* after f fails? Shouldn't the rest of the command not be executed?

Comment: @JefréN Yes it's important when the first condition failed, he don't need to continue. Exemple false && echo 2, will never print 2. It's the dual with ||, true || echo 2 will never print 2 because the first condition is true.

Comment: Are you trying to say that because `&&` and `||` are equal precedence, all the possible combinations are tested?

Comment: @JefréeN Not all the combinations are tested.